# gdb bt frame disassemble

Tags: function, gdb, frame

My Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
Here is the backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0e77af34 in show_stats(req_obj_s*, stats_s*, int*) () from /lib/libpd_ip.so.0.0
#1  0x0e78ad40 in bdPktMgrGetNext () from /lib/libpd_ip.so.0.0
#2  0x0e78b888 in bdPktMgr(void*) () from /lib/libpd_ip.so.0.0
#3  0x0e6f4f94 in pd_thread_creation () from /lib/libpd_api.so.0.0
#4  0x0fa893b0 in ?? () from /lib/librbn_pthread_np.so.0.0
#5  0x0d592210 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x0d3d11d0 in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x0e78b888 in bdPktMgr(void*) () from /opt/ipos/lib/libpd_ip.so.0.0
(gdb)
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function _Z9bdPktMgrPv:
```

My question is that why the function is different in frame 2.

Comment: `_Z9bdPktMgrPv` is just the mangled C++ name for `bdPktMgr(void*)`

Answer (score 1):

> My question is that why the function is different in frame 2.

It's not. Read about name mangling [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).